# Get Data From text file on CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, text

I just create a project, and I want to get data from server with .text format. I want to get specific data from it. I work with CodeIgniter. I need your advice or link to read. I've read at CodeIgniter user guide, but the data so small.

Thank you for everything.

Comment: you want to fetch text file on server and make it available to download, or you want to generate text file and download it?

Comment: I want to get the data from the file and put it on a view, to edit the data on the relevant data. For ex, I get ip.address from nana.txt and I change it in view then save it. And the ip.address on nana.txt will updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) to get file contents directly to your variable. No CI-specific code needed at this point.